# python re for exact match number and string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to match a string if it exactly matches, while ignoring case. Below is the code where my string value is different but still matching.

```
import re
k = "999"
v = "99"
if (re.search(v, k , re.IGNORECASE)):
   print "xyz" 
k = "AAA"
v = "aa"
if (re.search(v, k , re.IGNORECASE)):
   print "xyz"
```

In above code `k = 999 , v = 99` but matching and `k = AAA, v = aa` matching. What I exactly need is if `k= 999` and `v = 999` then match other all cases should not match. like wise `k = AAA` and `v = aaA` should match (Meaning ignore case) if `k =AAA` and `v = aa` should not match.

Comment: Why are you using regex at all? A simple comparison gives you what you need: `if v == k: `.

Comment: i need ignore case , i will also compare strings

Comment: So your not just going to be using data like in your answer?

Comment: Just accpet @Stephen Rauch 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean..... `if k == v:`?

Comment: i need ignore case , i will also compare strings

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need RegEx for this, but for whatever reason if you do, ypou can use start of string and end of string to match.

```
k = re.compile(r"^99$")
```

Comment: i need ignore case , i will also compare strings

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do a case insensitive compare is to use `lower()` or `upper()`:

**Code:**

```
def matches(str1, str2):
    return 'matches' if str1.lower() == str2.lower() else 'does not match'
```

**Test Code:**

```
data = (
    ("999", "99"),
    ("999", "999"),
    ("999X", "999x"),
    ("999Xx", "999x"),
)

def matches(str1, str2):
    return 'matches' if str1.lower() == str2.lower() else 'does not match'

for datum in data:
    print('%s %s %s' % (datum[0], matches(*datum), datum[1]))
```

**Results:**

```
999 does not match 99
999 matches 999
999X matches 999x
999Xx does not match 999x
```